# Synchronize access to two matrices

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have n-threads that access to two shared matrices in the following way:

```
    if (matrix2[i][j] <= d){
        matrix1[i][j] = v;
        matrix2[i][j] = d;
    }
```

I tried with a unique mutex before the critial section but the performace are very poor.
Which is the best way to synchronize this code? A matrix of mutex? Alternatives?

Comment: One would prefer to have no critical sections at all, e.g. by separating work between threads if possible (so for example thread 0 only deals with row `i=0`, thread 1 only with `i=1` etc.). If the critical sections are completely separate (i.e. there's no situation where a thread would need to lock more than one mutex at the same time) then matrix of mutexes might be reasonable. But if any thread would lock two mutexes at the same time, you get change of deadlocks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you have to lock and unlock a resource frequently, it will be slow. Perhaps there is a way to write it using shared data less often.

Comment: You first need to specify what is the type of your matrices. Anyway, if we suppose that `matrix[i][j]` just returns a reference to the stored element, these elements are not bit-compressed (each element is stored in a separate memory location), they are properly aligned in memory, and no two threads access the same `[i][j]` (each particular i-j pair is mapped to a single thread only), then you don't need any synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

> A matrix of mutex?

It's rare for very fine-grained locking to perform better than a smaller number of locks, *unless* keeping them locked for a long time is unavoidable. That seems unlikely here. It also opens the door to deadlocks (for example, what if one thread runs with `i=1, j=2` at the same time as another thread with `i=2, j=1`?).

> I tried with a unique mutex before the critical section but the performance are very poor.

What synchronization you need depends on your access pattern. Are multiple threads all performing the operation shown?

If so, do you really need to do that in parallel? It doesn't seem expensive enough to be worthwhile. Can you partition `i,j` regions between threads so they don't collide? Can you do some other long-running work in your threads, and batch the matrix updates for single-threaded application?

If not, you need to show what other access is causing a data race with the code shown.